# Select certain users from Player class by username?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

In my code, I wish to be able to select the `Player` objects of certain users simply by 
a). Creating the user with `createPlayer("Test")`, then being able to call that user with `Game.Player.Test`, so that I can do things such as log their name with `console.log(Game.Player.Test.Name)` etc.

This is what I have so far, my problem is pretty much everything below `findPlayer`, it is returning undefined

```
        var User = 'iJava';
        var Players = [];
        function Game(Object, Name) { 
            this.Type = Object
            this.Name = Name;
        }
        function Player(Username) {
            this.Name = Username            
            this.getInfo = new Game("Player", this.Name)
            this.Type = this.getInfo.Type
            this.Move = function() { console.log("Moved",this.Name) }
        }
        function createPlayer(Username) {
            if ($.inArray(Username, Players) == -1) {
                new Game.newPlayer(Username)
                Players.push(Username);
                console.log("Created user "+Username+"!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("The user "+Username+" already exists!");
            }
        }
        function findPlayer(Username) {
            return Game.getPlayer.Username;
        }
        Game.getPlayer = Player;
        Game.newPlayer = Player
        Game.Player = function(name) { findPlayer(name) };
        createPlayer(User);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
var Game = {Players: []};

Game.Player = function Player (name) {
    if (this.constructor[name])
        throw new Error("A player with this name already exists");

    // Store player on constructor for fast access, as well as in
    // Game.Players array to easily iterate over all players. 
    Game.Players.push(this.constructor[name] = this);
    this.Name = name;
}
// Use prototype to define object methods only once
Game.Player.prototype.Move = function () {
    console.log("Moving player: '" + this.Name + "'");
}

new Game.Player("MyPlayer");
console.log(Game.Player.MyPlayer);
```